# Orbit of stars in a galaxy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, galaxies, celestial-mechanics

Do all stars orbit around the galactic center? If yes what makes them orbit around the center , what object creates such a massive force which makes stars millions of light years far away from the center to orbit around it?

If not how is the orbit of a star within a galaxy determined?

Comment: The Milky Way is a medium large galaxy and is a few tens of thousands of parsecs across. Call 100,000 light years. That's still a long way, but it isn't "millions of light years".

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Stars orbit in the gravitational potential of the entire galaxy. That is a bit different to thinking about planets orbiting in the solar system, where the potential is totally dominated by the Sun.

In the case of a galaxy, the density of matter may be centrally concentrated, but it is spread out over the whole galaxy. The central concentration means that circular orbits are approximately centered on the Galactic centre and that more eccentric orbits (approximately ellipses, but they are not necessarily closed curves) have a focus near the Galactic centre.

If the potential were spherically symmetric (which it isn't), stars would orbit just as if all the mass interior to their orbit was concentrated at the Galactic centre. They would be unaffected by mass exterior to their orbit. This is known as [Newton's shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem).

Lastly, a typical orbit for a star has a radius of tens of thousands of light years.

Comment: Hi Rob 
So it doesn't necessarily mean that they orbit around the center of the galaxy ??

Comment: @kevinkrupa see edit.